# How can I use the command "pwd" in R to load data?

Tags: r

In my Rscripts, normally, I use the easiest way to load files.

```
data1 <- read.table("~/user/document/data/cache/distances.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

But I would like to use this script in other computer, therefore the path will change.

The cache directory always be there with the file distances. In my Bash script I'm using this to avoid this problem:

```
WORKING_DIRECTORY=`pwd`/cache
```

But I have no idea how can I use that in R.

What I would like is something like:

```
data1 <- read.table("'pwd'/cache/distances.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

Comment: See the get and set working directory commands `?setwd` And `?getwd`. That may help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getwd()` with the `file.path` to get the path to your files:

```
file.path(getwd(), "cache/distances.dat")
```

In your case:

```
data1 <- read.table(file.path(getwd(), "cache/distances.dat"), quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

Comment: Or `path.expand("~/cache/distances.dat")`

Comment: or `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), "cache", "distances.dat")`